# appending a parameter with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm struggling with an htaccess rewrite command

what I have is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/
```

I have a few URLs going to the same folder, some of them redirect to subfolders, which then run different templates. However, I also need to append a parameter to the end of every page that is redirected, eg, ?template=2

I can't just add it to the end manually, because some pages already have parameters, eg /?product=1 - so the second parameter needs to have the & sign not the ? sign.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Is there a chance somebody could retitle this so "parameter" is properly spelled?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to [add the QSA flag on the end of your rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/?template=2 [QSA,L]
```